# How to push a viewController before dismissing modal view controller with Storyboards?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller, uistoryboard

While trying out storyboards for one of my projects I came across something for which I don't have a good solution;

I have a navigation-based application which shows a UITableViewController. The tableView is populated with user-created elements. Tapping an element cell brings up the detail view controller. The user can create a new element by tapping a button in the tableView. This brings up a modal view, which will handle the creation.

Now, when a user is done with creating the element and dismisses the modal view controller, I want the user to see the corresponding new detail view controller and not the tableview. But I can't figure out how to achieve this in storyboards.

Does anyone have a good pattern for this?

**Current situation**

```
TableView --(tap create)--> creation modal view --(finish creating)--> TableView
```

**Should be**

```
TableView --(tap create)--> creation modal view --(finish creating)--> detail view
```

Comment: Added my own answer below. Any better patterns that may do this with storyboards are still appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best pattern I could come up with, is the same as the old pattern in code.

Add a property `(nonatomic, weak) UINavigationController *sourceNavigationController` to the modal view controller. When it becomes time to dismiss the modal view controller, add the following code:

```
DetailViewController *detailViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewController"];
detailViewController.element = newlyCreatedElement;
[[self sourceNavigationController] pushViewController:detailViewController animated:NO];
```

And to make sure the `sourceNavigationController` get set properly, add the following code in the `prepareForSegue:` of the TableView:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"newElementSegue"]) {
        [[segue destinationViewController] setSourceNavigationController:self.navigationController];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put the creating view controller in a navigation controller and link the creation view controller to the detail view controller as well with a push segue. When you finish creating the data it will direct to an instance of detail view controller.

If you want to navigate back from details view directly to the table view, you can add a property to the details view controller, say `@property (nonatomic) BOOL cameFromCreationViewController;`. You can set this property in `prepareForSegue:` in the source view controller. In the details view make your own back button, and when it's tapped, you can do this:

```
if(self.cameFromCreationViewController){
     [self.presentingViewController dismissViewController];
}
else {
     [self.navigationController popViewController]
}
```